# Force Field/Rigid Body Rotation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to sort of float objects towards the camera and have them drift rotate. I have set up a force field and a turbulent force but they only seem to be effecting the position of the objects and not rotation.

I've attached some screenshots of the setup, any help would be greatly appreciated as I'd love to play around with forces a lot more, but can only seem to find tutorials related to particles!

Thanks

[image: Force field setup]

[image: Force Field settings]

[image: Turbulent settings]

[image: Rigid Body settings]

Comment: Ok, so if i let the simulation run a bit longer the do eventually start rotating. I guess the new question is how to control the rotation to happen as soon as they start moving and how to constrain the direction to 'towards the camera'?